# Problem with physics object tunneling using Nez and monogame

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics

I was using the Nez engine with monogame to create a platformer, I made the player character an ArcadeRigidBody and the map collision shapes were handled by a TiledMapRenderer, but I noticed that when I leave the player falling, and move the window which severely decreases the FPS the player falls through the ground. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?